# How to fit sizes of background and foreground layer using CSS flexbox

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

In my web app, I have a background and an overlay layer, both *can* grow, and if one of them grows, the other *should* grow to the same size. In other words: I have a stack of HTML elements, and their sizes should be in sync, following the biggest element.

Is there a way to do this with a plain flex layout? (*without* `float` and `transform` hacks)

Here's some pseudo code to outline my problem:

```
<container>
   <background>has min-height of container height. Can grow (and cause scrollbars) if dynamic content takes more height</background>
   <foreground>some overlay that should cover the background completely (following the size of the 'background' element, not the size of the 'container' element.)</foreground>
</container>
```

Comment: we need to see the issue and not only the solution you provide

Comment: @TemaniAfif Not sure what you're missing ...

Comment: everything, you described your own problem and we are not able to see it ... there is no code, so how can this be helpful ? we need to see the issue. What if someone have a better solution ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think my answer pretty much shows the structure of my problem. If you find better way of styling this, I'd highly welcome it. Actually my answer generalized my original problem, so I added it to the question.

Comment: Actually what I understand is that you had an issue with your own app and you founnd a workaround but we have no idea what you wanted to do? what is the purpose? what was the issue? how this can be helpful for future reader?  ... you described something too broad and you provided a code doing something we don't know what. I see a text over background that we can easily do with multiple background so I don't see how this is related to flexbox.

Comment: @TemaniAfif it feels like repeating myself: I want to use flexbox all the way down in my angular 5 app, I have a component with a child component, and this child component needs to be overlayed in some cases. The overlay should exactly cover its sibling component. The generalization of this (an what I thought others might be interested in) is how to stack (overlay) items in a flex container in a way that they all get the same size while not hard-coding the item size and letting room to grow. If I'm still failing to get the message across, I'm sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169926/discussion-between-benjamin-and-temani-afif).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution:

- use flex items with each `100%` size of the flex container,
- set margin-left to `-100%` for each of the items except for the first one.

```css
/* demo setup */

* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 16pt;
}

section {
  flex-basis: 0;
  border: 3px dashed blue;
}

.background {
  background-color: beige;
}

.overlay1 {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  text-align: right;
}

.overlay2 {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5) 0%, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0) 100%);
}

/* actual solution */

.flex-stack {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-stack>* {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  margin-left: -100%;
}

.flex-stack> :first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-stack">
  <p class="background" style="min-height:8em;">
    This is the background layer.
  </p>
  <p class="overlay1"><br> this is some overlay box.
  </p>
  <p class="overlay2"><br><br>
    <textarea style="resize: both;">This is resizable content: drag the lower left corner of the the textarea.
  </textarea><br> this is another overlay box.
  </p>
</section>
```